# jquery percentage with scrolltop

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am new to jQuery and trying to change this new script which fades in a div after scrolling 100px, to fading in after 100%. It doesn't seem to work when I add in a %.

```
$("#theDiv").hide();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 % ) {
        $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Because adding a percent sign is no longer a `number` value. It doesn't make it anything unless you put quotes around it, and then you can't compare it like you would a `number` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you refer 100% to the user's actual window height, try this line instead:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height() ) {
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect